# How to generate .xls file with dynamic file name

Tags: phpexcel

I'm generating .xls file by loading an existing .xls file and by doing some cell mapping filling values in the excel sheet form. While saving it I've given a static file name to save it in the server. Now I want the file name to be dynamic in such a way, I'm passing some request_id in the URl to run my code and I want that code to be appended in the File Generated.

For example, In my code I'm saving it by
$objWriter->save('Form.xls');

While running my code, I'm passing a request_id like,
/Form.php?request_id=377

So, I want the request_id to be appended in the excel file getting saved, i.e Form_377.xls

Please advise. Thanks in advance!
Krishna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$objWriter->save('Form' . $_GET['request_id'] . '.xls');
```

you get the params from url by [$_GET['param']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) so you can use that for your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You should do this :

```
$objWriter->save('Form_'.$_GET['request_id'].'.xls');
```

Comment: @ Dead Man - Thank you very much for providing the solution :)

Comment: Shouldn't this be the accepted answer, seeing that both solve the problem in the same way and this one was posted earlier (even if it was only for a few seconds)?